# Is there a way to change id of data frames appended in Pandas?

Tags: django, pandas

so I have two data frames, and used `.append()` method to merge them vertically.
However, I get an error of which I assume the cause is duplicate id's. Here is a sample of the data frames.

```
   A   B
1  a1 b1
2  a2 b2
3  a3 b3
4  a4 b4
```

```
   A  B
1  q1 w1
2  q2 w2
3  q3 w3
4  q4 w4
```

Now the merged data frame looks like this:

```
   A  B
1 a1 b1
2 a2 b2
3 a3 b3
4 a4 b4
1 q1 w1
2 q2 w2
3 q3 w3
4 q4 w4
```

Now, I'd like to change the id of each row. Would that be possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ignore_index=True` parameter in [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```